# CLLocationManager Delegate methods not being called - CLLocationManager set up in main thread

Tags: ios5, cllocationmanager, clgeocoder

I have the following function that I believe is being run in the main thread (it is the event assigned to a button click)

```
-(void)startTracking:(CLLocation*) targetLocation
{
    NSLog(@"Target location: %@", targetLocation);
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    self.targetRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:targetLocation.coordinate radius:10 identifier:@"Destination Region"];

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.targetRegion];
    //[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"Target region: %@", self.targetRegion);
 }
```

The only reason I say "i think", is that before this can be run, I get the targetRegion details in a block run on another thread.

```
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:self.address completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
        for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
        {                    // Process the placemark.
            NSLog(@"Got Placemark : %@", aPlacemark);
            //newDestination.destination = aPlacemark.location;
        }
        //self.Destination.destination = [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] location];
        self.targetLocation = [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] location];
        self.startTrackingButton.enabled = true;
        self.stopTrackingButton.enabled = true;
    }];
```

Is this the reason why the delegate is not being called...?